# Unable to load the data from ELK in Databricks notebook

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

> I'm unable to load data from ELK when calling remote index but able to load the data from local index

```
df = (spark.read
       .format( "org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
       .option( "es.nodes", hostname) \\ 
       .option( "es.port", port)
       .option( "es.net.http.auth.user", user)
       .option( "es.net.http.auth.pass", password)
       .option( "es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
       .option("es.net.ssl", "true")
      .load("{INDEX NAME}")
)
display(df)
```

> Local Index - logs-*
> Remote index - *:logs-*
>
> I'm getting this error
> org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot find mapping for *:logs-* - one is required before using Spark SQL